# align image with text in the middle (responsive)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day, I am trying to center two col-md-6 where the left side with the text is aligned in the center beside the image. here are my css:

```
.full_width {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.align-row {
  display:flex !important;
}

.align-row > *
{
  align-self:end !important;
}
```

I tried to align it with align-row but the text goes to the bottom, any help would be appreciated.

[image: issue]

```
<div class="full_width">
        <div class="align-row row align-items-center">

            <div class="col-md-6 text-align-center">

              <span>
                <h2 class="color-mwc-blue">SELF-CARE IS SELF-LOVE: 2019 WELLNESS GOALS</h2><br>
                <h2 class="color-mwc-orange">REGISTER</h2><br>
                <h2 class="color-mwc-blue">TO ENJOY A WELTH OF DEALS FOR WELLNESS</h2>

              </span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <img src="img/_stock_replace_this_1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

PS, I am using bootstrap 4

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 4?

Comment: yes im using bootstrap 4

Comment: Check the ans. Hope it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `align-self:center;` to align center element

```
.align-row > *
{
  align-self:center;
}
```

```css
.full_width {
  width: 100%;
}

h2{
    font-size:16px;
}

.align-row {
  display:flex;
}

.align-row > *
{
  align-self:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="full_width">
        <div class="align-row row align-items-center">

            <div class="col-md-6 text-align-center">

              <span>
                <h2 class="color-mwc-blue">SELF-CARE IS SELF-LOVE: 2019 WELLNESS GOALS</h2><br>
                <h2 class="color-mwc-orange">REGISTER</h2><br>
                <h2 class="color-mwc-blue">TO ENJOY A WELTH OF DEALS FOR WELLNESS</h2>

              </span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `d-flex` and `align-self-center` boostrap default class to align the content equally center.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 d-flex">
        <div class="align-self-center">
            <h2 class="color-mwc-blue">SELF-CARE IS SELF-LOVE: 2019 WELLNESS GOALS</h2>
            <br>
            <h2 class="color-mwc-orange">REGISTER</h2>
            <br>
            <h2 class="color-mwc-blue">TO ENJOY A WELTH OF DEALS FOR WELLNESS</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```